# RETURN VALUE FUNCTION ASYNC AWAIT IN RESPONSE EXPRESS

Tags: javascript

I want to return the value returned by the function getData()
I understand that I can't return a promise but how can I return only the data value obtained in the asynchronous function.
A response from express

Help please...

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getData() {
    req = 'hello';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.abc.com.py/buscar/' + req);
    

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const $news = document.querySelectorAll('.item-article'); //Corresponde a la clase de Noticias de la pagina
        const dataNews = [];

        ......


            dataNews.push({
                fecha,
                enlace,
                enlace_foto,
                titulo,
                resumen,
            });
        });

        return dataNews;

    })

    return (data);
}
```

This Response

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var getData = require('../public/javascripts/script');

//import getData from '../public/javascripts/script';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/consulta', (req, res) => {
  data = getData.then(val => val);
  res.json(data);
  
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Send your response in the `then` callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/consulta', async (req, res) => {
  data = await getData();
  res.json(data);
})
```

OR

```
router.get('/consulta', (req, res) => {
  getData().then(data=>res.json(data));
})
```

Comment: I have not been able to solve the problem

For option 1: 
"await has no effect on the type of this expression"

For option 2: 

getData.then is not a function
TypeError: getData.then is not a function

Comment: Option one will throw a syntax error.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer. You have to call the function ofcourse, my bad.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer with a brief explanation of the code and how it solves the original question? Code alone often isn't super helpful to people looking at this in the future.